# Wallch not working since Plasma 6

Tags: plasma, wallpaper, kde-neon

I use KDE neon 6.0 (the KDE OS, based on Ubuntu) and I have recently updated to Plasma 6. Since then I've noticed that the desktop wallpaper was not updating and I searched for information about Variety not working on Plasma 6. After not finding I anything I've noticed that Wallch wasn't running because it fails to start giving the error.

```
app-wallch@autostart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
app-wallch@autostart.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: /usr/bin/wallch: No such file or directory
```

After that I was suggested to check systemctl And I found this that I'm not sure if it's related to the issue

● apparmor.service loaded failed failed Load AppArmor profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Wallpaper Changer Issue

It seems that your WALLpaper CHanger is missing, as in not installed anymore.  This is indicated by `/usr/bin/wallch: No such file or directory`.  Let's see if it's still installed with: `which wallch`

### Reinstall Wallch Or Reset Service?

Depending on the outcome of the above command, you may need to [reinstall wallch](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-wallch-in-ubuntu), or remove the service and re-enable it:

1. Go into your Autostart Preferences
2. Remove Or Edit the entry for Walch to match the output in the `which` command above.

For AppArmor, please see my partially answered question: [AppArmor Error preventing removing AA, Repairing AA or install new apps with Apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766380/apparmor-error-preventing-removing-aa-repairing-aa-or-install-new-apps-with-apt/766608#766608). The OP there was never able to tell me if my approach worked or not, and no Answer was ever accepted.  If AppArmor involves more work beyond what's already in my answer, please submit a separate question.

Comment: I have obteined any result with the command which:

manuelcam@ManuelCam:~$ which wallch
manuelcam@ManuelCam:~$ 

Does this mean that the program it's not installed?

Comment: That is correct.  Use the link I provided to reinstall it.